# How to create Drupal Articles Thumbnails and display it on homepage

Tags: 7

I would like to know what is the BEST WAY to generate thumbnails in drupal?
I need to create a semi news style website in Drupal that requires me to GENERATE THUMBNAILS AUTOMATICALLY from Articles I created. I attached a sample website screenshot from a similar website I am trying to imitate.

Is there a Good Drupal module can you recommend? or much better a Drupal function I can insert in PAGE.TPL.PHP to generate thumbnails from my articles or posts and display it in the front page?

Thank you in advance sirs.

[image: creation of website thumbnails in drupal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view module for your display

1. Go to structure -> views -> add new view
2. Checked -> create block
3. Set the required fields based on image

   [image]
4. Click save button
5. Check If block is exist or not in Structure -> Block
6. If block exist that block Drag particular region .
7. Click "configure" and set specified page

And also float:left used to article body summary is displayed in left side

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module to achieve above...

For more details visit [documentation](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/views) page of views module.